# Multiple reviews or one big review?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I'm just putting my SQL code out for review:

[Part 3: Layer 4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158139/507)
[Part 3: Layer 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158113/507)
[Part 3: Layer 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158052/507)
[Part 3: Layer 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158007/507)

Would it have been better to do this in a single review? Or is the style of doing logical units better?

Comment: The only reasonable answer to this question is ... it depends™ I see nothing wrong with splitting a large codebase into multiple logically coherent units, but you may miss out on reviewers pointing out issues with the interactions of said logical units. Then again large reviews tend to take longer or become zombies, so ...

Comment: I think that having smaller chunks makes it easier for reviewers to find the time to do a review.  For what it's worth, I plan to review one or more of these parts, but I just haven't gotten to it yet.

Answer (score 5):

For large amounts of code...yes I would definitely consider breaking it up. However, you should do so logically to aid understanding. Perhaps certain sections of your code achieve a certain task/goal and you can extract those sections for review asking the community whether there would a better way to satisfy the goals of those sections. Just a suggestion though, all I know is I'd find it very difficult to digest pages of code and then review it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions based on looking at your posts(Layer4, Layer3):

- Ask for smaller code reviews rather than big one
- Be specific on what you want to be reviewed. Rather than describing what the code is suppose to do in detail, ask specific questions where you've doubts or need second opinion